# NetApp Usable Capacity Magic

Tags: netapp, capacity

I'd like to know the exact math of how to calculate usable capacity on a NetApp filer's aggregates. Out of experience I've been using a magic factor of 0.65-0,7  times the net RG capacity of all the aggregate's RGs.

Just as a simple example:
3 shelfs, each with 24 1TB spindles with 3 spares form an aggregate with RG-size 15, ie 3 RGs, one plex, total 45 TB capacity. The usable capacity from the RGs is ((15-2)*3) = 39TB. There are no volumes on this aggregate and the aggregate snap reserve is 5%.

The system reports a usable capacity of 27TB on that aggregate which is pretty much 39TB times the magical factor. Can anyone provide some insight?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a NOW account, [this article](https://kb.netapp.com/support/index?page=content&id=1011114) should help answer your question.  In general, you start with the physical capacity of the disk, subtract space lost to parity (depends on whether you are using single- or dual-parity and the size of your RAID groups), 10% for system overhead, and 20% for the default snapshot reservation.  You can adjust the snapshot reservation, but the remaining overhead is fixed.

Regarding parity: using single parity, you lose one disk worth of space for each RAID group (and two disks worth of space for dual parity).

Comment: If you read my post you'll see that I accounted for all of that.

Comment: I did read your post.  You asked for "the exact math of how to calculate usable capacity on a NetApp filer's aggregates".  The linked document provides the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

A few things are missing that account for the difference:

- Right-Sizing to adjust for different amounts of space presented by different hardware manufacturers, firmware, etc...
- The difference between SI units (GB = 10^9) and binary units (GB = 2^30)
- Block checksum storage

The whole lot is explained pretty thoroughly by [this blog post](http://blogs.netapp.com/efficiency/2009/08/measuring-storage-efficiency-part-ii-taxes.html).

You can get the physical size vs. the "Right-Size" of the disks by running "sysconfig -r" at a filer.  Put that in your formula, take binary units into account and it'll work out.  You can also get the "right-size" of various disks from the storage management guide for ONTAP.